# Looping through a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to loop through this JavaScript object but it's only returning the last key.

Here's my code

```
var array = [
    {
        "outfit": {
            "url": "http://www.nintendo.co.uk",
            "title":"T-shirt",
            "price":"£20"
        }
    },
    {
        "outfit": {
            "url": "http://www.nintendo.co.uk",
            "title":"T-shirt",
            "price":"£720"
        }
    },
    {
        "outfit": {
            "url": "http://www.nintendo.co.uk",
            "title":"T-shirt",
            "price":"£9920"
        }
    }
];

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){

    console.log(array[i]);

    $('.slide .content').each(function(index){
        if(i == index) {

            console.log(i + "==" + index);
            var contentDiv = $('.slide .content')[index];

            contentDiv.innerHTML = "";
            contentDiv.innerHTML = '<a href="'+ array[i].url +'">'+ array[i].title + '<span>'+ array[i].price +'</span></a>'
        }


    });

}
```

I'm basically trying to loop through the data, extracting it for a look-book carousel. Then append each piece of data in $('.slide .content') for each slide of the carousel.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: Duplicate keys will get replated. So your object will have only one key value pair.

Comment: In your object, both properties are named "outfit". So during enumeration, only the second one shows up. If the property names are different, both of them will appear.

Comment: the outfit is repeated and the second one overrides the first

Comment: Thanks all. Gabriel Terry comment worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

```
var array = [
    {
        "outfit": [
            {
                "link": {
                    "url": "http://www.nintendo.co.uk",
                    "title":"T-shirt",
                    "price":"£20"
                },
            },
            {
                "link": {
                    "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk",
                    "title":"Trousers",
                    "price":"£60"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "outfit": [
            {
                "link": {
                    "url": "http://www.nintendo.co.uk",
                    "title":"Dress",
                    "price":"£920"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
array.forEach(function(value, index ){
    value.outfit.forEach(function( outfitValue, outfitIndex){
        console.log(outfitValue.link.title);
    });    
});
```

**Result**

- T-shirt
- Trousers
- Dress

https://jsfiddle.net/jzpL8dnm/13/

---

I changed the structure of your code. It may help you to solve your problem.

```
var array = [
    {
        "outfit": {
            "link": {
                "url": "http://www.nintendo.co.uk",
                "title":"T-shirt",
                "price":"£20"
            },
            "link": {
                "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk",
                "title":"Trousers",
                "price":"£60"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "outfit": {
            "link": {
                "url": "http://www.nintendo.co.uk",
                "title":"Dress",
                "price":"£920"
            }
        }
    }
];

for(var key in array){
    console.log(array[key]);
}
```

Comment: Please add this to jsbin or jsfiddle... in the 1st outfit... the 2nd link is not being outputted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that if we are having same keys in a JavaScript object then on traversing JavaScript object by transpiler/compiler it will get the updated info of keys. So keys should be unique if you really want to achieve it Associative array are the most convenient way because indexing will help you to retrieve data either the data is duplicate or not.

second way: if you want to use only js object then create array in js object where you have same key.

Answer (score -2):

You have the same keys.
Keys in JS objects must be unique.

Comment: This must be made as comment. Not an answer.

Comment: Okay thank you. Made the keys unique and it all working.

Comment: Vignesh Raja, I have no reputation for comment. please remove the negative reputation

Comment: Nasir Altaf if this helps you, please vote it as the correct answer